# Async await does not await

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to loop through an array and for each id, update the model, then push the result in another array

this is my code :

```
async function getSortedAnimals() {
  var i = 0;
  var sortedAnimals = [];
  ids.forEch(async (id) => {
    i++;
    const animal = await this.animalModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          order: i,
        },
      },
    );
    sortedAnimals.push(animal);
  });
  console.log(sortedAnimals);
  return sortedAnimals;
} //function
```

when I console log, the array is empty, I don't know why ! it's like it does not await for the loop to end.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! On top of the solution mentioned above, do also note that your `forEach` is spelled wrong -- you have `forEch` instead.

Comment: You are starting up one async function for each iteration of the loop. When the loop finishes you have N async functions running in the background and an empty array. The only thing that's wrong here is your expectation/understanding of the code.

Comment: use normal for loop insted of forEach. forEach is not promise aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the answers say that forEach ignores Promise(async/await).
This is a common situation in Javascript. I'd like to suggest to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of for..of loop.

```
const findOneAndUpdate = async (id) => {
  return await this.animalModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    {
      $set: { order: i },
    }
  )
} 
const getSortedAnimals = async () => {
  const sortedAnimals = ids.map(async id => await findOneAndUpdate(id))
  return await Promise.all(sortedAnimals)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result promises are being ignored in the `forEach` construct.
You can replace it with a `for...of` as below:

```js
async function getSortedAnimals() {
    const ids = [1,2,3];
    const sortedAnimals = [];
    for (const id of ids) {
        const animal = await findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: id}
        );
        sortedAnimals.push(animal);
    }
    console.log(sortedAnimals);
}

async function findOneAndUpdate(o) {
    return o._id + 1;
}

getSortedAnimals();
```